# Can't find NSButton for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, button, nsbutton

i am using xcode4 and storyboard to create an application form.
I would like to add check button and found using NSButton is the best way, but I could not find NSButton in the object library. 
Would you please tell me how to find it?

Comment: You should mark an answer as "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark icon next to the answer you like best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSButton is cocoa class and available on MacOS, not iOS. iOS does not have standard check box so you'll have to use UIButton with custom images for selected/deselected state instead of that.

Or (may be better) you can use standard `UISwitch` control which serves similar purpose

Comment: +1 for mentioning the switch, which I of course missed in my simultaneous answer, even though he was asking for a checkbox :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Now I understand why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

When you are programming for iOS, there is no `NSButton`, because that is a MacOS X Cocoa class. Instead, you want to use the CocoaTouch classes, prefixed with `UI`, in you case a `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is to create a two buttons with custom images for example:button1 and button2 are there.
In view will appear you have to show button1 only,when user click on button1,hide button1 and show button2,even if user click on button2,you have hide button2 and show button1